# How to add a image in a border

Tags: html, css

So, I'm having a problem with CSS and Html.

I want To fit the image in the border that the h1 element is.

The image CSS code:

```css
.img{  
  height:50px;
  width:70px;
}
```

The Html code:

```html
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <img class="img" src="[ProfilePic][1]" alt="Avatar">
   <h1 class="center"> Test</h1>
   <div style="text-align:right">
      <button class="button" href="*">Compras</button>
   </div>
</body>
```

The Center class:

```css
.center{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100 px;
    background-color: lightblue;

}
```

The h1 class:

```css
h1{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 68px
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code the code you have provided is not sufficient

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti Check if the new code i added  can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the image into the `<h1>` tag directly.

Also, your `border-radius` property for your class `center` isn't applied, since you have an extra space.

```css
.img{  
/*
  height:50px;
  width:70px;
  */
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;

}
h1{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: solid;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 68px
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center"> <img class="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Avatar"><br>Spectric</h1>
   <div style="text-align:right">
      <button class="button" href="*">Compras</button>
   </div>
```

Or you can use a `<div>` to surround the two like so:

```css
.img{  
/*
  height:50px;
  width:70px;
  */
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid;
}
h1{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 68px
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<img class="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="Avatar"><h1>Spectric</h1></div>
   <div style="text-align:right">
      <button class="button" href="*">Compras</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: @Spetric Thanks bro, i changed the code a little and it's great.

Comment: @G4ver_Dev Glad to help :P. Also, it's "Spectric" ;)